# Synaptics touchpad not detected while switching user on Unity

Tags: unity, 14.04, touchpad, synaptics

Synaptics touch pad is detected and works well if a single user is logged in . However if we swtich to another user , mouse no longer works for the second user . You could either switch using the Lock/Switch user account menu OR using CTRL+ALT+F8 .

**Log file for Screen0 (CTRL+ALT+F7) -> Synaptics touch pad works fine.**

```
            [    20.205] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/event17)
            [    20.205] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "evdev touchpad catchall"
            [    20.205] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "touchpad catchall"
            [    20.205] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "Default clickpad buttons"
            [    20.205] (II) LoadModule: "synaptics"
            [    20.205] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so
            [    20.205] (II) Module synaptics: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
            [    20.205]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 1.7.4
            [    20.205]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
            [    20.205]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 20.0
            [    20.205] (II) Using input driver 'synaptics' for 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'
            [    20.205] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: always reports core events
            [    20.205] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event17"
            [    20.232] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: x-axis range 1472 - 5472 (res 58)
            [    20.232] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: y-axis range 1408 - 4448 (res 106)
            [    20.232] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: pressure range 0 - 255
            [    20.232] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: finger width range 0 - 15
            [    20.232] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: buttons: left right
            [    20.232] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Vendor 0x2 Product 0x7
            [    20.232] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: touchpad found
            [    20.232] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: always reports core events
            [    20.264] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input9/event17"
            [    20.264] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 12)
            [    20.264] (**) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) MinSpeed is now constant deceleration 2.5
            [    20.264] (**) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) MaxSpeed is now 1.75
            [    20.264] (**) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) AccelFactor is now 0.040
            [    20.264] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
            [    20.264] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration profile 1
            [    20.264] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
            [    20.264] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
            [    20.264] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: touchpad found
            [    20.264] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/mouse1)
            [    20.264] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Ignoring device from InputClass "touchpad ignore duplicates"
```

**Log file for Screen1 (CTRL+ALT+F8) -> Second user Synaptics touch pad not detected**

```
            [ 32380.253] (II) Using input driver 'synaptics' for 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'
            [ 32380.253] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: always reports core events
            [ 32380.253] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event17"
            [ 32380.260] (EE) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Synaptics driver unable to detect protocol
            [ 32380.260] (EE) PreInit returned 11 for "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
            [ 32380.260] (II) UnloadModule: "synaptics"
            [ 32380.260] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/mouse1)
            [ 32380.260] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Ignoring device from InputClass "touchpad ignore duplicates"
```

**Output of xinput on Screen 0**

```
            ⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
            ⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
            ⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
            ⎜   ↳ MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (ene_ir)            id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
            ⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
                ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
                ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
                ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
                ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
                ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
                ↳ HP Webcam                                 id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
                ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
                ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
                ↳ ENE eHome Infrared Remote Receiver        id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Are there any known  workarounds till a proper fix can be made available ?

Comment: I have the same problem (and similar logs). If I start a guest session from the cog menu: no touchpad. BUT if I lock the screen, then "switch users" and start the guest session from lightdm: touchpad works! Then get back to first user: no touchpad (and the GUI sometimes freezes when I try to open the touchpad settings). BUT if I disconnect my mouse and start a guest session from the cog menu: touchpad works! This bug is very weird! Did you have a mouse connected? And how where you switching users (starting a new session)?

Comment: I reported this bug in Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/1362218 . You may want to report there as affected.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a workaround to solve the problem:

Create a file `/usr/local/sbin/mousecheck` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash

OLDVT="x"

while sleep 1
do
VT=$(fgconsole)
if [[ "$VT" -ne "$OLDVT" ]]; then
  modprobe -r psmouse
  modprobe psmouse
  OLDVT="$VT"
fi
done
```

Make this script executable:

```
chmod a+x /usr/local/sbin/mousecheck
```

You may now start the script by using

```
sudo /usr/local/sbin/mousecheck
```

and check if it's working. Finally you can enable the hack permanently by adding

```
/usr/local/sbin/mousecheck &
```

to file `/etc/rc.local`. Be careful: Add it before the line

```
exit 0
```

and don't forget the ampersand (&) at the end of the line.

Comment: Add to what file?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the device driver :

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics && sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

Comment: Synaptics driver works on Cinnammon desktop .Problem seems to be only with Unity

Comment: Uninstalling the synaptics driver seems to solve the problem . But the touchpad  is quite unusable as a touchpad . I wonder if may be related to this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/868400

Answer (score 0):

According to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm/+bug/1247388, a workaround is to run:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

This enables the touchpad for the user, but disables it for the other one (I tested). But this needs admin privileges, so I don't know what's the solution for a normal user.

I also tried this with the guest session, but executed the two commands with the first (admin) user in a virtual console, and it enabled the touchpad for both users.
But, interestingly, when I tried this with another admin account instead of the guest, doing the same thing in the virtual console enabled the touchpad for only one of the users. Weird.

---

Another workaround (from https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/868400):

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

Running this before switching users seems to fix the issue, but breaks the touchpad settings.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to Ubuntu 14.10 finally fixed the problem . Yipee. Tested with 14.10 using nouveau driver .

Comment: A simple kernel update (to the kernel version in Ubuntu 14.10) probably would have resolved it too. :-]

Comment: Possibly .. But I had regularly applied patches and updates which never resolved it .Also  it seemed like a problem with Unity as it worked well with Cinnamon desktop . Also latest update seems to have fixed some issues with Nouveau ( so I can finally ditch Nvidia drivers hopefully )